# Angular Universal app with IIS Node not serving CSS Files

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular5, angular-universal

I have built Angular universal app which has dist and dist-server with server.js and node_modules folder.

When I run `node server.js` , I'm able to load the app but when I deploy in IIS with IIS NOde , I'm only getting index.html , CSS and JS files are not loaded.

```
    'use strict';

    require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');
    require('reflect-metadata');

    const express = require('express');
    const ngUniversal = require('@nguniversal/express-engine');
    const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

    const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist-server/main.bundle');


    function angularRouter(req, res) {
// Only 1st time we are getting request here --1
and log will be my Virtual APP directory Name 
      console.log(req.url);
      res.render('index', {req, res});
    }

    const app = express();

    app.engine('html', ngUniversal.ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
      providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
      ]
    }));
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', 'dist');

    app.get('/', angularRouter);

    app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/dist`));

    app.get('*', angularRouter);

    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      // console.log('Listening on port 3000');
    });
```

I have tried different URL rewrite rules in web.config but it doesn't work because once the index.html is loaded then from there all request are routed through express , so express I'm unable to figure out how to make express use static files when Routed from IIS

Note: App is working absolutely fine when I run node server.js i.e app listening on localhost:3000

Comment: Are all your files in dist? or a subfolder of dist?

Comment: @David In dist folder itself

Comment: Try adding this before the first app.get:  app.get('*.*', express.static(`${__dirname}/dist`));

Comment: The problem is virtual directory name , it is looking inside the dist folder not just the file I want but along with virtualDirName/filename.js, I think need to rewrite URL in web.config to skip the  virDirName

Comment: @sudhir - Is this solved ? If yes how you solved ?